# R: loading a table with number as the column heading all were wrongly added a X, how to solve it?

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to load a table to R with some of the column heading start with a number, i.e. 55353, 555xx, abvab, 77agg

I found after loading the files, all the headings that start with a number has a X before it, i.e. changed to X55353, X555xx, abvab, X77agg

What can I do to solve this problem.  Please kindly notice that not all column heading are start with a number.  What should I do to solve this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: set `check.names = F` within the call to `read.table` (or `read.csv`). The `X` is added to make a *syntatically valid* name (see `?make.names`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your issue will be solved by adding `check.names=FALSE` to your `read.table()` call.

For more information see `?read.table`

Comment: I don't think that all questions need sample data, do they? The question was pretty clear and you were able to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: @mrdwab, you are correct. Andrie also agreed, and edited my answer accordingly.